# What does mutability guarantees mean in erc721

Tags: erc-721, payable, interfaces

Some functions from ERC-721 interface contain `payable` modifiers.

`function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;`

I was wondering why it is `payable` and found from [EIP-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) that explains why.

> Solidity issue #3412: The above interfaces include explicit mutability guarantees for each function. Mutability guarantees are, in order weak to strong: payable, implicit nonpayable, view, and pure. Your implementation MUST meet the mutability guarantee in this interface and you MAY meet a stronger guarantee. For example, a payable function in this interface may be implemented as nonpayble (no state mutability specified) in your contract. We expect a later Solidity release will allow your stricter contract to inherit from this interface, but a workaround for version 0.4.20 is that you can edit this interface to add stricter mutability before inheriting from your contract.

Does this mean that when a function in the interface includes `payable` and when it is implemented, it can be changed to anything? such as `public`, `view`,  `pure`?  or did it mean that it can only be changed to **nonpayable** which is `nothing`? I don't get why it is not

`function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;`

in the first place. Also the definition `Mutability guarantees` is hard to understand. Can someone explain this in a simpler way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that when a function in the interface includes payable and when it is implemented, it can be changed to anything?

Yes, `payable` is the least-strict form of mutability, so your implementation of the function can use a stricter mutability if you want it to.

> Also the definition Mutability guarantees is hard to understand. Can someone explain this in a simpler way please?

Basically, any function that is `payable`, can implicitly anything that a non-payable function can do.

Any non-payable function can implicitly do anything that a `view` function can do.

And any `view` function can implicitly do anything that a `pure` function can do.

But the same is not true in the opposite direction.

So if a function in the interface is `view`, its a guarantee that your function can read data if you want it to, but not write data or accept `msg.value`.

Comment: Great answer. For reference, just wanted to point out the first bullet point in ERC-721's caveats section. Changes were made to Solidity as part of passing ERC-721 and this note provides additional context and answers to "OMG why does transfer cost money!!LL??".